# Changing date format - incorrect year

Tags: php, date

**The code:**

```
$expiration_date = "24th Dec, 2012";
var_dump( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $expiration_date )));;
```

**The output:**

```
string(10) "2011-12-24"
```

Why is PHP not parsing the year correctly (showing 2011 instead of 2012)?

PHP Version: 5.2.17 on Centos 5.7

Comment: strtotime is handy, but it's not omniscient. It's not even close to artificially intelligent. At best it's artificially stupid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) does not support the ordering of your date (see 2<sup>nd</sup> [table](http://php.net/manual/datetime.formats.date.php)).  Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) class instead:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("jS M, Y", "24th Dec, 2012");
var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d')); // string(10) "2012-12-24"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it has something to do with the format of $expiration_date.
Try putting month infront of the date. It worked just fine for me.

```
$expiration_date = "Dec 24th, 2012";
```

Answer (score 1):

The input to the strtotime function must be in a [format strtotime can understand](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).